# React Js Appointment Calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I need your help.

Is  there already a React js event calendar, wich is totaly FREE-to-use .. also commercially.

I should be able to change calendar weekday and month names in my language.

It should be easy to bind to a Event-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a resource](https://react.rocks/tag/DatePicker) that can help you make the type of calendar you would like to see.

To take an example, [here is a date picker that includes an internationalization option](http://clauderic.github.io/react-infinite-calendar/#/internationalization/locale?_k=yb5qoj).  It's just a matter of importing the component, setting the configuration, then rendering it out to the page:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import InfiniteCalendar from 'react-infinite-calendar';
import 'react-infinite-calendar/styles.css'; // only needs to be imported once

// Render the Calendar
var today = new Date();
var lastWeek = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);

render(
  <InfiniteCalendar
    width={400}
    height={600}
    selected={today}
    disabledDays={[0,6]}
    minDate={lastWeek}
  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If you have any specific issues with the code, we'll certainly be able to help out.